# Secondary groups not getting set on login

Tags: nis

I have two servers, one with SLES9 SP4 and one with SLES11 SP1. SLES9 has bash 2.05b.0(1) and SLES11 has bash 3.2.51(1).

Both servers are configured to use the same NIS master where they get both password and group settings. The /home directories are automounted and the same on server1 (SLES9) and server2 (SLES11).

user1 logs in to server1 and successfully gets his default and secondary groups:

```
uid=1413(user1) gid=111(group1) groups=111(group1),112(group2),130(group3),211(group4),1000(group5)
```

user1 logs in to server2 and only gets his default group assigned:

```
uid=1413(user1) gid=111(group1)
```

I don't see anything strange in /var/log/messages or on the NIS server. Could it be something to do with .bashrc or .profile files that are executed differently between SLES9 and SLES11? Or must it be something to do with NIS? Any ideas?

Comment: How is your nsswitch.conf configured on server2? Look at the passwd and group entries to see if NIS is actually used. Can server2 access the NIS server?

Comment: Using getent or ypcat on both server1 and server2 I get the same results. Also I have tried to login with different a different user and that user never has problems.

Comment: The /etc/nsswitch.conf files are the same except for mdns2_minimal on server2 and not on server1.